# Mapbox obtaining longitude and latitude coordinates and place them into HTML form value

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to create a function that whenever a user clicks on the map, it will automatically records the longitude and latitude and store them into variables. These variables will be used as the hidden input value for the HTML form.

Javascript:

```
    map.on('click', function(e) {
        var latitude = e.latlng.lat;
        var longitude = e.latlng.lng;
        console.log(latitude)
        console.log(longitude)
        document.getElementById("longtitude").value = JSON.stringify(longitude);
        document.getElementById("latitude").value = JSON.stringify(latitude);
    });
```

HTML Hidden Input:

```
<body>
        <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
          <form method='POST'
          id = "comment-form"
          action="https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/coogkakrw27a5"
          class="form-container">
    
            <div if="form_alerts"></div>
            <h2>Comment</h2>

            <input type="hidden" id="longtitude" name="data[longitude]" value="">
            <input type="hidden" id ="latitude" name="data[latitude]" value="">
        
          </form>
        </div>
       </body>
```

I expected the hidden input value to change everytime the user clicks, but it does not seem to change at all. I am not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error assigning latitude and longitude variables. Use `var latitude = e.lngLat.lat; var longitude = e.lngLat.lng;` instead your e.latlng.lat and e.latlng.lng.

See it in action in this simple example `https://jsfiddle.net/ToniBCN/rjqawbn4/8/`